# screen.width and screen.height property is not supported by Safari browser

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

I'm having this following code where in I'm trying to open a pop up window to the center of the screen. This works fine in Firefox, Chrome and in IE too but doesn't work in Safari.
I feel the Safari browser is not able to interpret the `screen.width` and `screen.height` properties. Or is it something else? I'd appreciate any help! Thanks in advance :)

```
   function openPopup(url){
       var date = new Date(); //To uniquely identify a window, I'm appending this to the window name.
       window.close(); //Closing the parent window.
       var width=650, height=375;
       var leftC =(screen.width / 2) - (width/ 2);
       var topC =(screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
       window.open(url, "winName_"+date.getTime(), 'location=0, toolbar=no, scrollbars=0, resizable=no, width='+width+', height='+height+', top='+topC+', left='+leftC);            
}
```